# Javascript evaluation failed: input('#login_field','dummy') on running karate feature

Tags: karate

I am getting error

"java.lang.AssertionError: failed features:
feature.demo-01: demo-01.feature:16 - javascript evaluation failed: input('#login_field','dummy'), ReferenceError: "input" is not defined in  at line number 1"

on running the below feature

Feature: browser automation 1

```
Background:
  * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true }
  # * configure driverTarget = { docker: 'justinribeiro/chrome-headless', showDriverLog: true }
  # * configure driverTarget = { docker: 'ptrthomas/karate-chrome', showDriverLog: true }
  * configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', showDriverLog: true }
  # * configure driver = { type: 'geckodriver', showDriverLog: true }
  # * configure driver = { type: 'safaridriver', showDriverLog: true }
  # * configure driver = { type: 'iedriver', showDriverLog: true, httpConfig: { readTimeout: 120000 } }

Scenario: try to login to github and then do a google search

  Given driver 'https://github.com/login'
  And input('#login_field','dummy')
  And input('//input[@id='password']', 'world')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be on an old version of Karate. Use 0.9.5.

Maybe try the ZIP Release first and get familiar: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: Thank you Peter. While using 0.9.5 , the chrome browser is not opening and shows error com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: demo-01.feature:20 - path: $, actual: '{"message":"invalid session id\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)"}', expected: 'Incorrect username or password.', reason: not a sub-string

Comment: Done .Accepted answer